# Extending Custom User Model - Multiple User Types in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new(er) to django but very excited to learn such a versatile framework. I'm working on a project where I will have 2 user types, account 1 and account 2. Account 2 will have the ability to "add a user" to their account. Think of account 2 as a company who can add users to their company.

So far I've extended the generic User model and have created a class for each of the account types but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Ultimately I will want to create a login/register form for each of the account types - similar to how ziprecruiter functions so some advice on how to approach that would be awesome too if possible.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email           = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class account1(User):
    profile         = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True)
    # account 2 fields here
    first_name      = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name       = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    location        = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'account1_user'

class account2(User):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    # account2 user fields here

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'account2_user'
```

Am I doing this correctly? What's the best approach to creating a login/registration form for each type of account? What's the best approach to creating a model that will allow for a user of a user type (if that makes sense)?

Comment: What is the question tho?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb is no matter what your business logic, **always use one User model for your application**. if you want multiple types of user then you could use attributes to determine user types. For example, in my application i want three types of user, `Admin`,`Broker` and `Client`. Here is how we can do this.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_client(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, phone, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_client = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_reseller(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, phone, password=None):
        user = self.create_client(username, first_name, last_name, email, phone, password)
        user.is_reseller = True
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_admin(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, phone, password=None):
        user = self.create_reseller(username, first_name, last_name, email, phone, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        is_superuser = None

        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "phone"]
        EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

        objects = UserManager()

        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=DefaultModel.MAX_LENGTH)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=DefaultModel.MAX_LENGTH)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=DefaultModel.MAX_LENGTH)
        phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)

        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_reseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        # storing timestamps for users.
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        added_by = models.ForeignKey("self", models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

So what i did, i'm using custom `UserManager` Class which is responsible for generating `User` Model objects and i've implemented methods for generating for all types of users `Client`, `Broker` and `Admin`.

`DefaultModel` is actually class which i'm using as constants for setting default values for models. Here is what it looks like:

```
class DefaultModel:
    MAX_LENGTH = 1000
    MYSQL_UNIQUE_LENGTH = 255
```

If you don't know about `objects` in models you may learn about it from Django docs.
[Custom User Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)
[Django Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. My question now is that User model should just contain fields that are relative to both user types? What about for when fields that pertain to broker but not client and vice versa - how would you approach that? I assume maybe creating a profile class for each of them?

Comment: You can override the `User.clean` method to add some conditional validation that raises `ValidationErrors` when conditionally required fields are missing

Comment: @Nick Creating individual class for each type of user is also better idea. It's better to add validation in that model (as Lain suggested for user model) to check if user type is Client or admin depending on for what user you are creating. And yes user model can contains fields which are relative to both users. It's depends on you what you like to have and which way is much easier to maintain application in future.

Comment: Would going the route of using Choices to determine which type of user it is be beneficial at all?